# Finding all the roots of the function x = a*sin(x) in Python

Tags: python, root

I have to find the number of solution depending on the parameter a. While solving the equation numerically using scipy.optimize.root I get some numbers which aren't root of the function. For example for 
x = 7*sin(x) i get numbers -7.71046524 and 7.71046524. My code is:

```
a = np.linspace(-5, 5)

def fun(x):
    return x - b*np.sin(x)

for i in a:
    solutions = []
    b = i
    c = abs(int(round(i)))
    for j in range(-c, c+1):
        y = root(fun, j)
        if (round(y.x[0], 3) not in solutions):
            solutions.append(round(y.x[0], 3))
    print(len(solutions))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use [`scipy.optimize.root`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root.html#scipy.optimize.root), the return value contains `x` the solution array **and** the `success` boolean flag. You need to filter out any result where `success` is `False`.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import root

a = np.linspace(-7, 7)

def fun(x):
    return x - b*np.sin(x)

for i in a:
    solutions = []
    b = i
    c = abs(int(round(i)))
    for j in range(-c, c+1):
        y = root(fun, j)
        if y.success and (round(y.x[0], 6) not in solutions):
            solutions.append(round(y.x[0], 3))
    print(i, solutions)
```